# ElasticSearch : Multiply scores between ‘distance_feature’ and ‘dismax’

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

Imagine I have 3 queries:

> ```
> "distance_feature": { ... time... }
>
> "distance_feature": { ... location... }
>
> "dis_max" : { ... }
> ```

Currently, to combine it I do this:

> ```
> "query" : {
> "bool" : {
>    "must" : [
>
>   "distance_feature": { ... time... },
>   "distance_feature": { ... location... },
>   "dis_max" : { ... },
>
>     ]
>   }
> }
> ```

The problem is that the score of computes as a sum, and I'm looking for a way to "multiply" instead.

I have try with function score, but I can't put them there, right ?

Do you have any idea or solution ?

Thanks